# Confused by the useEffect cleanup behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How the useEffect hook's clean up function only contains or works with the previous states. As we know the useEffect process including it's cleanup runs **after** a re-render.

Here in **TestComponent**, the "*incrementTrigger*" state used in cleanup function contains it's previous value.

```
const TestComponent= () => {
  const [incrementTrigger, setIncrementTrigger] = useState(1);

  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setIncrementTrigger(incrementTrigger + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Component Updated " + incrementTrigger);
    return () => {
      console.log("Clean Up - " + incrementTrigger);
    };
  }, [incrementTrigger]);

  return (
    <div className="mainContainer">
      <h2 className="text">
        This is a temporary component to observe the behaviour of useEffect
        hook.{" "}
      </h2>

      <button onClick={toggleHandler}>Toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: What is a [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#closure)

Comment: There is a single `incrementTrigger` variable that is shared, through a closure, by all the functions inside `TestComponent`. Also, please make sure your posts include a question, there's no `?` in your post or an explanation of actual versus expected behavior. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> How does the useEffect hook's clean up function only contains the previous state?

Because the effect captures the value of `incrementTrigger` when it's called.

The cleanup function the effect function returns has captured the same value.

Comment: If this is the answer, this post should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JuanMendes A generic "How do closures work?" is likely not to tell OP much, though.

Comment: I think it will help more than just saying what you said above (which would make more sense as a comment). This is such a basic feature of JavaScript, we don't need another answer on StackOverflow. They need to understand the basic feature. If they have a real question after they at least read about closures, then they can ask a well posed question.